# Why is Gmail API returning null when I try to get the raw mail?

Tags: java, email, gmail-api, mime-message

I have written this code to convert Message(Gmail API) to MimeMessage(Javax.internet)

```
public static MimeMessage createMimeFromMessage(Session mailSession, Message message)throws Exception{
        String raw=message.getRaw();
        byte[] decodedEmail=Base64.decodeBase64(raw);
        InputStream emailInputStream=new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedEmail);
        MimeMessage mimeMessage=new MimeMessage(mailSession,emailInputStream);
        return mimeMessage;
    }
```

Here  getRaw() returns null. I am getting the Message using the following-

```
public static List<Message> listMessagesMatchingQuery(Gmail service, String userId,
      String query) throws IOException {
    ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list(userId).setQ(query).execute();

    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    while (response.getMessages() != null) {
      messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
      if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
        String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
        response = service.users().messages().list(userId).setQ(query)
            .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }

    return messages;
  }
```

This is based on reverse engineering this code on Google's website(https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending)-

```
public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage emailContent)
            throws MessagingException, IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        emailContent.writeTo(buffer);
        byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
        String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes);
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
        return message;
    }
```

The end goal is to convert Message to MimeMessage. I can convert eml files to MimeMessage type without error, but I am not sure why this is going wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you implement any logs to see at what point your code behaves differently from expected?

Comment: Like I said...it retrieves the messages based on query. Each message has size 2 with id and thread id with an option for expanding the field which shows a few more numbers that I couldn't make sense of. I can print the id, get the attachment names. After the listMessageMatchingQuery call, it goes immediately to the createMimeforMessage where it returns null for getraw

Answer (score 2):

`messages().list` only returns a list of messages with id and threadId. You then need to use `service.users().messages().get(userId, messageId)` to recover the message. If you go to their API explorer, there's an option to set format. You need to select "raw", thus making the statement-

```
service.users().messages().get(userId, messageId).setFormat("raw").execute()
```

to get the raw message.

Additionally, to get content and attachment you need to do the following-

```
try{
            mimeParser = new MimeMessageParser(GmailApiUtils.createMimeFromMessage(mailSession,message));
            mimeParser.parse();
            System.out.println("From: "+mimeParser.getFrom());
            System.out.println("Content: "+mimeParser.getHtmlContent());
        } catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
```